# android authentification using a password generated with symfony

Tags: php, android, symfony

I'm importing a password using an xml file from a script (created with symfony).

I store the password in the databse but I don't know the used encryption to compare.

is there the same encryption function in android ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password

Comment: I visited this site before asking the question.
the password is encrypted using sha512 algorithm but when I try to encrypt with the same salt using DigestUtils.sha512Hex function I dont get the same result saved in the database.